# Apache 2 - Errors logged in SSL_Error_Log but I cannot locate the configuration file

Tags: linux, https, apache2

We have an issue with timeouts to a URL using HTTPs / 443. The server under this URL is using Apache 2.

I can see the errors in the ssl_error_log under /var/log/httpd but I cannot actually locate the configuration file for SSL.

I have checked httpd.conf and there are no Virtualhosts and no configuration lines to say log SSL errors on ssl_error_log.

There are no firewalls on this server at all, so I think its miss -configuration causing the timeouts.

Any ideas on where this would be located? Im using Centos 6

Comment: Look in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`

Comment: @deeh nope this path doesnt exist :( thanks anyway. I temporarily resolved it by restarting apache service